# vim location-list: how to go to first location if at last location

Tags: vim

I have mapped `gn` to `:lnext<cr>`; how can I keep pressing it to cycle thru the location list, i.e. go to first if at last location?

Thanks

Comment: `gn` is a wonderful command. I would recommend against overriding it. See `:h gn`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The secret is to use `:try` and `:catch` the same as you would in other languages. You are looking to catch the following errors `E553` or `E42`.

```
nnoremap ]l :try<bar>lnext<bar>catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E\%(553\<bar>42\):/<bar>lfirst<bar>endtry<cr>
```

The command was inspired by Tim Pope's [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin.

I would also recommend against mapping of `gn`. The `gn` command is very handy motion that actions on the search pattern. See `:h gn`.

For more information see:

```
:h :try
:h E553
:h E42
:h :lnext
:h :lfirst
```

Comment: Thanks; I am having trouble to use it as one-liner; but it worked after creating a function to do that. Also thanks for the tip on avoid overriding `gn`.

Comment: @wangzq I have corrected some formatting issue that should make the mapping work

Comment: thanks again, it is now working; I learned a lot from this question.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution taken straight from my configuration:

```
" wrap :cnext/:cprevious and :lnext/:lprevious
function! WrapCommand(direction, prefix)
    if a:direction == "up"
        try
            execute a:prefix . "previous"
        catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E553/
            execute a:prefix . "last"
        catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E\%(776\|42\):/
        endtry
    elseif a:direction == "down"
        try
            execute a:prefix . "next"
        catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E553/
            execute a:prefix . "first"
        catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E\%(776\|42\):/
        endtry
    endif
endfunction

" <Home> and <End> go up and down the quickfix list and wrap around
nnoremap <silent> <Home> :call WrapCommand('up', 'c')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <End>  :call WrapCommand('down', 'c')<CR>

" <C-Home> and <C-End> go up and down the location list and wrap around
nnoremap <silent> <C-Home> :call WrapCommand('up', 'l')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-End>  :call WrapCommand('down', 'l')<CR>
```

Comment: FYI, this snippet is now part of [a larger plugin](https://github.com/romainl/vim-qf).